# How to reduce load time Retrieving large database table with 12,000+ rows in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, database-performance, laravel-5.8

***Hi there,***
I have a 'subscribers' table in my DB, having more than 12,000 rows and the number is increasing gradually.
When I open the subscriber view in the browser, it take a minute or more to load all the data and then arrange pagination in the datatable.

Here is my code of **SubscribersController**

```
public function index()
    {
        $subscribers = DB::table('subscribers')->get();
        return view('subscribers')->with('subscribers',$subscribers);
    }
```

*Is there anyway which can increase the performance of the page loading.

Thanks in Advance!*

Comment: Use Pagination to only load a chunk of the files? Do you really need to load 12k entries  at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a similar problem and I resolved it byy using `composer require yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle:"~9.0"`. With datatables you can use server-side loading which will take about 5 seconds to load 15000 records.

First, install the package following the guide: [install yajra/datatables](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables).

Second, set a route to the function that will retrieve the data in the controller, like:

```
Route::get('/subscribers/render-subscribers-datatable', 'SubscribersController@render_subscribers_datatable')->name('render_subscribers_datatable')->middleware('auth');
```

Third, configure the datatable in the view to get and process the data, like:

```
$('#subscribers').DataTable({
    responsive: true,
    processing: true,
    deferRender: true,
    serverSide: true,
    bLengthChange: false,
    searchDelay: 500,
    pageLength: 10,
    ajax: '{{ route('render_subscribers_datatable') }}',
    columns: [
        { data: 'active', orderable: false, searchable: false, className: "text-center"},
        { data: 'client_name' },
        { data: 'date_of_birth' },
        { data: 'personal_id_number' },
        { data: 'partner_number' },
        { data: 'phone' },
        { data: 'delivery_address' },
        { data: 'email' },
        { data: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false, className: "text-center"},
    ],
});
```

Configure the columns properly to your project...

Forth, work out the controller, like:

```
public function render_subscribers_datatable(Request $request)
{
    // Check if Request Came From Ajax
    if($request->ajax())
    {
        // Get data
        $dump = DB::table('tbl_subscribers')->select()->get();

        // Return datatable
        return Datatables::of($dump)->make(true);
    }

    // Else, redirect
    // redirect with message
    return redirect()->route('home')->with('error', 'cant process the request.');
}
```

Hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Use pagination. I think you don't need to load all 12k records at once.

Have a look here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/pagination

Your code should look like this:

```
public function index(){
    $subscribers = DB::table('subscribers')->paginate(100);
    return view('subscribers')->with('subscribers',$subscribers);
}
```

This will load only 100 subscriber at once and you will have access to next ans previous records.

Hope this helps you

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer.
I have reviewed this solution earlier, but the problem is, I have to load all the subscriber at once.

Comment: Can you tell me for what reason? Maybe there is another solution

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `$subscribers = DB::table('subscribers')->get();`, you should use

`$subscribers=DB::table('subscribers')>paginate(numbers_of_row_you_want_to_retrive e.g 10);`

This will retrieve only 10(for this example) entries form the database at a time.
You can use `{{ $subscribers->links() }}` to paginate the data in your view page. Each page will contain 10 entries (for this example) and you can cycle through pages to get the other entries.